# How to run a function whenever unknown anchor tags are clicked in Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `div` with `v-html` that displays data from a database:

`<div id="Content" v-html="`${Content}`"></div>`

Within the `${Content}` that is presented, there can be any number of `a` tags with links to other external pages. I need to parse these and then add an `@click` handler to each of them. An example would be:

`<p>Calm down, Marty, I didn't disintegrate anything. The <a href="example.com/m">molecular structure</a> of Einstein and the car are completely intact. They wanted me to build them a bomb, so I took their <a href="example.com/d">plutonium</a> and in turn gave them a shiny bomb case full of used pinball machine parts.`

To transform into this:

`<p>Calm down, Marty, I didn't disintegrate anything. The <a @click="validateLink()" href="example.com/m">molecular structure</a> of Einstein and the car are completely intact. They wanted me to build them a bomb, so I took their <a @click="validateLink()" href="example.com/d">plutonium</a> and in turn gave them a shiny bomb case full of used pinball machine parts.`

Or alternatively, just instruct Vue.js to run `validateLink()` whenever any `a` tag is clicked within the `div id="Content"` tag.

I can get all the `a` tags within the `div` like such:

```
const AnchorTags = document.getElementById('Content').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

But I am at a loss of how to then get the `validateLink()` function to run on click of these tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content of [v-html](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-html) is treated as plain HTML - you cannot place Vue directives inside.

Luckily for you this specific problem can be solved easily using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) e.g. attaching the handler to the parent element + inspecting the target (clicked) element...

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      html: `<p>Calm down, Marty, I didn't disintegrate anything. The <a href="example.com/m">molecular structure</a> of Einstein and the car are completely intact. They wanted me to build them a bomb, so I took their <a href="example.com/d">plutonium</a> and in turn gave them a shiny bomb case full of used pinball machine parts.`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick(ev) {
      if(ev.target.tagName === 'A') {
        console.log('Anchor clicked -', ev.target.href)
      }
      
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div v-html="html" @click.stop.prevent="onClick">
  </div>
</div>
```